# Testing class by mocking getter

Tags: unit-testing, testing, kotlin, junit, mockito

I try to test a class which as two properties with getters where the one getter calls a static method. I want to mock the getter with static method to test the parsing logic of the other getter. The problem is that can't access the variable via the getter and thus calling the mock.

I searched the kotlin documentation for the getters and setters but didn't found a solution.

```
class ClassToTest() {
    val firstname: String
        get() = this.fullName.split(" ")[0]

    val fullName: String
        get() = SomeService.getFullName()
}
```

```
class ClassToTestTest() {
    fun `firstname should return first part of the fullName`() {
        val classToTestMock = mock<ClassToTest>()
        `when`(classToTestMock.fullName).thenReturn("Walter White")
        assertEquals(classToTestMock.firstname, "Walter)
    }
}
```

I expect to get "Walter" back but instead the `ClassToTest.firstName` accesses the variable directly and not the mocked getter.

Can someone point me to the right direction? :D

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it return, then?

Comment: Since it doesn't use the getter mock and directly accesses the variable it tries to invoke the static method which returns an empty string and thus fails the assertEquals.

Comment: If a `val` is declared using `get() = ` then no actual backing field (variable) gets introduced. You can inspect the bytecode to make sure

Comment: Only `getFullName()` method

Comment: Actually, I see that `when(classToTestMock.name)` stubs `name` property, but not `fullName`

Comment: Good to know that `val` with `get() =` introduces no actual variable. Oh I'm sorry name and fullName should be the same variable. I changed the naming to make it more clear. Is it possible to stub the `getFullName` method with `when(classToTestMock.fullName)` on a `val`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you are trying to test your `firstname` calculating property. For that you need to make your class and `fullName` property open.

```
open class ClassToTest() {
    val firstname: String
        get() = this.fullName.split(" ")[0]

    open val fullName: String
        get() = SomeService.getFullName()
}
```

`Mock` can work only with `open` (not `final` in Java) entities. In other way it will throw exception in runtime.

Then, to setup your test class just call following:

```
`when`(classToTestMock.fullName).thenReturn("Walter White")
```

P.S. I can't see field `name` in your class, so I replaced it with `fullName`. If I'm missed something, I wish you could get the point.

Comment: Yes you are right `name` should be `fullName`. I fixed it in my post. Thank you very much that works! Didn't know there was an `open` keyword.